# How to catch a 400 response in jQuery getJSON call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, http-status-code-400

In jQuery I want to fetch some data from facebook using the `$.getJSON()` method, but if the token is invalid, Facebook is returning the 400 status. How I can catch the error in `$.getJSON()` instead of `$.ajax()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this will work for you

```
$.getJSON("example.json", function() {
  alert("success");
})
.success(function() { alert("success 2"); })
.error(function() { alert("error occurred "); })
.complete(function() { alert("Done"); });
```

Comment: @Ludo-Offtherecord Isn't that because you are looking at a question answered in 2012?

Comment: I know, but we're living in 2019 now, and people (like myself) will still come across this so nice if they know why it's not working for them and what will work. I'm not saying your answer was wrong, i'm just saying it's not correct anymore.

Answer (score 7):

The jquery [Ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) offer two solutions, the first is the error function:

```
    error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
```

which detects and reports textual portions of error messages for you, the other is the status code feature (on the same page). Here's the example usage from that page:

```
    $.ajax({
      statusCode: {
        404: function() {
          alert("page not found");
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `complete(jqXHR, textStatus)` function callback and investigate the response and show the approprite message to the user.